# RIP Al Matthews, star of Aliens

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Al Matthews, best known for his depiction of Gunnery Sergeant Apone in the film *Aliens*, has passed away at the age of 75.

In addition to his iconic role he also appeared in a range of other science fiction properties including small parts in *Superman III* and *The Fifth Element* and recently reprised his role as Apone for the *Aliens: Colonials Wars* video game.

As well as enjoying success as a TV and film actor, Matthews was also a [gifted singer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZgOoa9NbAg) and a decorated veteran of the Vietnam War.